# Check for overlaps for several arrays in one query

Tags: postgresql, select

I have such table

```
create table tbl (
    id serial primary key,
    arr text[]
);
```

With such data

```
INSERT INTO tbl(arr) VALUES ('{dog, mouse}'), ('{fish, cat, rat}');
```

If my input is a single array - `{dog}` - everything is simple:

```
select id from tbl where arr && '{dog}'

| Id | 
|----| 
| 1  |
```

But what I need is the ability to pass several arrays as an input. For example with input `{cat}, {dog}` I expect output to be:

```
| Id | 
|----| 
| 2  | 
| 1  |
```

**And even more** how can I with input `{cat}, {bird}, {dog}` receive:

```
| Id   | 
|------| 
| 2    | 
| null | 
| 1    |
```

Looping through the input array and make a query for each its item is not an option, I want to fire as few requests as possible

Here's the corresponding sqlfiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5740d/2

Comment: If you flip the order in the WHERE clause, `where '{dog,cat,bird}' && arr`, you'll get rows with id 1 and 2 back. Is that sufficient for your purposes?

Comment: @bma not really, it returns the ids regardless the order of the input arrays. And the main purpose was to rely on the resulting ids order to map them to corresponding input arrays

Comment: Ah, got it. I missed that part.

Comment: it's not clear to me how your desired results even work could you explain them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you want something like this:

```
with param (p) as 
  ( values ('{cat}'), 
           ('{bird}'), 
           ('{dog}')
  ) 
select * 
from param left join tbl 
     on param.p::text[] && tbl.arr ;
```

Result:

```
   p    | id |      arr       
--------+----+----------------
 {cat}  |  2 | {fish,cat,rat}
 {bird} |    | 
 {dog}  |  1 | {dog,mouse}
(3 rows)
```